# Programmatically watch and restart node server

Tags: node.js, apache, webserver

I was getting tired of using FileZilla every time I wanted to push a change to my server hosting my website and so I set up a github repo and linked it to my server so that changes and pushed right to the server.

However, my backend is written in node and so each time I update my server.js file I have to restart the server. With "node server.js"

Is there a way to watch the file and programmatically restart the node server when an update is detected?

If it helps, my serve is Ubuntu Linux running apache2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try writing something yourself, or use one of the popular libraries that are already out there:

- https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor `supervisor server.js`
- https://github.com/remy/nodemon `nodemon server.js`

Comment: Thanks! I tried searching but I guess I didn't search deep enough!