# How to force pm2 to restart after a specific amount of time?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am using `PM2` to keep my node.js apps running.

Is there any way to have `PM2` restart my app every 1 hour?

Comment: Have you tried this https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1076 ?

Answer (score 9):

Put the code below in **pm2.js** and start it with `pm2 start pm2.js`

```
    var pm2 = require('pm2');

  pm2.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;

  setTimeout(function worker() {
    console.log("Restarting app...");
    pm2.restart('app', function() {});
    setTimeout(worker, 1000);
    }, 1000);
  });
```

More about this can be found [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1076).

Additional resources:

- [How can I programmatically shutdown a node program and restart it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517789/how-can-i-programmatically-shutdown-a-node-program-and-restart-it)
- [Programmatically watch and restart node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215370/programmatically-watch-and-restart-node-server)

Answer (score 4):

Use crontab.
Append this under your crontab file (run with `crontab -e`):

```
0 * * * * pm2 restart yourappname
```

Note that if you don't want to increment your pm2 restart counter, you can do something like this:

```
0 * * * * pm2 stop yourappname && pm2 start yourappname
```

Explanation:

`0`: on the 0th minute of the hour
`*`: every hour
`*`: every day
`*`: every month
`*`: every day of the week

Comment: Do you have any reference link for this?

Comment: [CronHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) 
"An asterisk (*) can be used so that every instance (every hour, every weekday, every month, etc.) of a time period is used."

Answer (score 4):

You can now use the pm2 built-in `--cron-restart` option, documented [here](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/). In your case, to restart every hour, you could add this to your pm2 config file.

```
    cron_restart: '0 * * * *',
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer. Everything you need is all part of pm2 and you don't have to include and maintain any cron scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. Then: `pm2 start name_of_your_file.js`.

In my case, it will exit the script after 15 minutes.

```js
/**************************************************************************
 * IMPORTS
 ***************************************************************************/

// NPM
const consola = require('consola')
const pm2 = require('pm2')

/**************************************************************************
 * START PM2 PROGRAMATICALLY
 ***************************************************************************/

pm2.connect((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(2)
  }

  pm2.start({ script: 'brain/domains.js' }, (error, apps) => {
    pm2.disconnect() // Disconnects from PM2

    if (error) {
      console.error(error)
      process.exit(2)
    }
  })

  // Kill the process if taking longer than expected
  setInterval(() => {
    pm2.describe('domains', (error, scripts) => {
      const exitTimeout = 15
      const uptime = Date.now() - scripts[0].pm2_env.pm_uptime

      if (uptime > exitTimeout * 60 * 1000) {
        consola.info(`Closing cluster after ${exitTimeout} minutes...`)

        pm2.restart('domains', (error) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error(error)
            process.exit(2)
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }, 30 * 1000)
})
```