# How make a node.js script to be restarted every hour?

Tags: node.js, auto-renewing, bitmex

I have a node.js script that creates a websocket connection to a crypto trading site (bitmex). It streams price data.

For some reason after an hour or two the stream goes bad and the prices (if streamed at all) are inacurate.

For now I restart it manually every hour but I need that to be done automatically. How can I do that?

Here is the code of the script:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime");

var couchbase = require('couchbase')
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://localhost/');
cluster.authenticate('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx');
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('test');
var N1qlQuery = couchbase.N1qlQuery;

let num_msg = 0;        
ws.onopen = function(){
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({"op": "subscribe", "args": [    
    "trade:XBTUSD",
    "trade:LTCZ18"]
    }))
};
ws.onmessage = function(msg){
    var response = JSON.parse(msg.data);
    num_msg++
    if(num_msg > 50) {
        var coin = response['data'][0]['symbol'];
        var price = response['data'][0]['price'];
        //console.log(coin + ":" + price + "\n");
        bucket.manager().createPrimaryIndex(
            function(){
                bucket.upsert(  coin, 
                                {
                                'price': price
                                },
                                function (err, result){
            });
        });

    }

};
```

EDIT: I missed to mention that currently I use Windows 7 system (eventhough I do need to move to Ubuntu or similar).

EDIT 2: Final version of my code :)

```
const cron = require("node-cron");
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var couchbase = require('couchbase');
var dateTime = require('node-datetime');

let now = new Date();
minutes = now.getMinutes() + 1;
if(minutes + 30 > 59) {
    minutes1 = minutes - 30;
} else {
    minutes1 = minutes - 30;
}
if(minutes > minutes1) {
    s_cron = minutes1 + "," + minutes +  " * * * *";
} else {
    s_cron = minutes + "," + minutes1 +  " * * * *";
}
cron.schedule(s_cron, () => {
    console.log("---------------------");
    console.log("Running Cron Job");
    var dt = dateTime.create();
    var formatted = dt.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');
    console.log(formatted);    
    // create bitmex ws
        var ws = new WebSocket("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime");
        // connect to couchbase
        var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://localhost/');
        cluster.authenticate('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
        var bucket = cluster.openBucket('test');
        var N1qlQuery = couchbase.N1qlQuery;

        let num_msg = 0;        
        ws.onopen = function(){
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({"op": "subscribe", "args": [    
                "trade:XBTUSD",
                "trade:LTCZ18"]
            }))
        };
        ws.onmessage = function(msg){
            var response = JSON.parse(msg.data);
            num_msg++
            if(num_msg > 50) {
                var coin = response['data'][0]['symbol'];
                var price = response['data'][0]['price'];
                //console.log(coin + ":" + price + "\n");
                bucket.manager().createPrimaryIndex(
                    function(){
                        bucket.upsert(  coin, 
                                        {
                                        'price': price
                                        },
                                        function (err, result){
                                            //bucket.disconnect()
                    });
                });

            }

        };
  });
```

Comment: You could use a cron job, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474280/how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-to-run-an-executable-every-hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 'node-cron': more at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron Hope that works.

Comment: Should I create a new script with node-cron or include it in the present script?

Comment: Just use it in the present script.

Comment: Look at this use case: https://scotch.io/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples   you may need to rearrange your code as shown.

Comment: Took me only a *few* hours to figure out this simple thing. Anyway thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `cron` to restart every hour. Your `crontab` entry would look like:

```
0 * * * * <command to restart your app>
```

If you can't or don't want to use your system `crontab` or equivalent (not sure what it would be on Windows), you can use `pm2`.

`pm2`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

For how to make `pm2` restart every hour, see https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1076 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/38062307/436641.

Another option would be `node-cron`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Comment: I am not really sure how to implement pm2 with the above script: can you help me with the code?